# Why can't I use Warp in Mass Effect?

Tags: mass-effect

I'm playing a Sentinel in Mass Effect 1. I have trained Warp (which I got as a bonus skill), but it doesn't appear in my power wheel so I can't use it. Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure it's not there, or is it just shaded red?  Powers that are shaded red are ineffective against the current target.

Comment: @MBraedley: I don't believe ME1 did such shading, but regardless, it's not there at all.

Comment: Oops, was thinking ME3.  According to [the wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Sentinel), ME1 sentinels didn't have warp.

Comment: @MBraedley: I picked it up as a bonus skill (will specify that in the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bug for adepts and sentinels.  The problem is that your power wheel has become too full so your bonus power cannot fit inside and, therefore, you lose it.  The only way to avoid this is by taking a weapon bonus power for adepts and sentinels or setting your bonus power as the hot-key bonus power before you have too many others while the bonus power still appears on the wheel.